# Как очищать очередь сообщений телеграм бота?

Tags: python, telebot

Запускаю бот через pytelegrambotapi. Допустим юзер написал когда бот был в офлайне - включаю бота - сообщения приходят пачками. Идёт дублирование. Как очистить эту очередь сообщений при старте?

Comment: вы решили проблему?

Comment: @Ildar увы, нет